# Add a column to a table in all schemas of a PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, ddl, postgresql-8.4

I have a Postgres 8.4 schema like below:

```
My_Database
 |-> Schemas
       |-> AccountA
       |-> AccountB
       |-> AccountC
       |-> AccountD
       |-> AccountE
      ...
       |-> AccountZ
```

All schemas have a table called `product` and I would like to add a boolean column to them at once. Is it possible to do this?

The only way I found until now is to run the below SQL account by account.

```
ALTER TABLE product ADD COLUMN show_price boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  _schema text;
  _sp
BEGIN
   FOR _schema IN
      SELECT quote_ident(nspname)  -- prevent SQL injection
      FROM   pg_namespace n
      WHERE  nspname !~~ 'pg_%'
      AND    nspname <>  'information_schema'
   LOOP
      EXECUTE 'SET LOCAL search_path = ' || _schema;
      ALTER TABLE product ADD COLUMN show_price boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE;
   END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

You can loop through the entries in system catalog tables with a [**`DO`** statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html). Requires **Postgres 9.0 or later**.
You can also [create a function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html). The `DO` statement uses the [procedural language plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) by default.

The only system catalog you need is `pg_namespace`, holding the schemas of a database. Loop through all schemas except known system schemas.

Make sure you are connected to the right database!

To add a column to a table with a **`NOT NULL`** constraint, you must also provide a default value to fill the new column. Logically impossible otherwise. I added **`DEFAULT TRUE`**, adjust to your needs.

Avoid SQL injection by quoting identifiers retrieved from system catalog tables properly. `quote_ident()` in this case. [There are more options. See:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49718/3684)

You need dynamic SQL. The primary "trick" is to just set the [**`search_path`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777) dynamically, so the same statement can be run over and over. The effect of [**`SET LOCAL`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) lasts till the end of the transaction. You can use `RESET search_path` or save the prior state and reset it if you need to do more in the same transaction with it (unlikely):

```
SHOW search_path INTO _text_var;
...
EXECUTE 'SET search_path = ' || _text_var;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do that in any event.

What you can do is automate it, by querying the catalog, and then wrap the code in a [`do` block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) (in Postgres 9.0 or later) or using a migration script. To find the needed query if you're unfamiliar with querying the catalog, the simplest is to use `psql -E`. It'll show hidden queries that get run when you enter `\dn` and `\dt`.