# Looping through all schemas

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a SQL query like so -

```
with referral as 
(
select (date_trunc('week', soc_date))::date as year_week, *
from p148.referral e
join p148.contact_accounts ca on 
e.contact_account_id = ca.id
where soc_date >= '2018-01-01'
and soc_date <= '2021-09-30'
),
owner as 
(
select * from owner1 
)
select *
from 
referral ra 
join owner o 
on o."name" = ra.name
```

I need to iterate through all the schemas in my database and run this query and save the result of it in the public schema. So, the public schema will have 1 table that will contain the result of this query from all schemas.

Comment: If `soc_date` isn't actually type `date` (like the name implies) but a `timestamp` or `timestamptz`, your query is incorrect, most likely. Please disclose the table definition and (always) your version of Postgres. Also, did you consider a view or materilalized view instead of the target table? And do your schemas change, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I'd simplify the query. I don't see a need for the second CTE - or any CTE for that matter:

```sql
SELECT (date_trunc('week', e.soc_date))::date AS year_week, * -- ??
FROM   p148.referral e
JOIN   p148.contact_accounts ca ON e.contact_account_id = ca.id
JOIN   public.owner1 o USING (name)  -- don't duplicate the column "name"
WHERE  e.soc_date >= '2018-01-01'
AND    e.soc_date <= '2021-09-30'
```

The `USING` clause only outputs a single copy of the join column `name`.
I still strongly doubt you want `SELECT *`. Will probably produce multiple `id` columns, which would have to be renamed. And it's pointless to store the effectively identical `e.contact_account_id` and `c.id` ...

Get the **set of existing schemas** in the database (minus system schemas you'll  want to exclude):

```sql
SELECT nspname
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_namespace
WHERE  nspname NOT LIKE 'pg\_%'
AND    nspname <> 'information_schema';
```

Related:

- [Add a column to a table in all schemas of a PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273246/add-a-column-to-a-table-in-all-schemas-of-a-postgresql-database/20277097#20277097)

Now build one copy of the query for every schema and execute dynamically. One option: **with `\gexec` in psql**:

```sql
SELECT format(
 $$INSERT INTO public.my_table (year_week, ...)
   SELECT (date_trunc('week', e.soc_date))::date AS year_week, *
   FROM   %1$I.referral e
   JOIN   %1$I.contact_accounts ca ON e.contact_account_id = ca.id
   JOIN   public.owner1 o USING (name)  -- don't duplicate the column "name"
   WHERE  e.soc_date >= '2018-01-01'
   AND    e.soc_date <= '2021-09-30'$$
 , nspname)
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_namespace
WHERE  nspname NOT LIKE 'pg\_%'
AND    nspname <> 'information_schema'\gexec
```

See:

- [My function returned a string. How to execute it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300700/3684)

Use `format()` with the format specifier `%I` as demonstrated to properly quote concatenated names and defend against SQL injection. See:

- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)

There are other options, it all depends ...

Comment: What is the impact of adding `\gexec` to production because I am getting a command not found error.

Comment: I provided a link to detailed explanation. Try it.